# Are there other ways to enter fastboot mode if the power button is broken?

Tags: boot-loop, fastboot, motorola-atrix-hd

I've dropped my phone (ATRIX HD) and now it isn't turning on. The thing is when I connect to charger it shows the green light and start to boot (Motorola logo appears) but then it keeps restarting forever.

I've read that to solve this you've enter fastboot mode and do some modifications. The problem is that I'm unable to enter fastboot when the phone is connected to the PC instead of the charger.

Since the power button broke it gets even harder because I have to use a mini screwdriver to press it (and it is very hard to press the "Volume Down" at the same time also).

So, is there any other way to pass the files needed for recovery or to enter fastboot mode?

Comment: Have you tried `adb reboot recovery` already?

Comment: No i haven't @ott-- , i thought the phone should at least be recognized by the computer to use adb. Have you any suggestions on that direction?

Comment: Did you already enable `Developer functions` in your `Settings`? There you can enable `USB debugging`.